# Minimal dominating subsets in infinite graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, set-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be any simple, undirected graph. A *dominating set* is a set $D\subseteq V$ such that for all $v\in V\setminus D$ there is $d\in D$ such that $\{v,d\}\in E$.

Is there an infinite graph $G=(V,E)$ such that there is a dominating subset $D\subseteq V$ such that for any dominating subset $D_1\subseteq D$ there is a dominating subset $D_2\subseteq D_1$ with $D_2\neq D_1$?

Comment: $G=(\mathbb N,\le)$ ?

Comment: @saf That doesn't work, since any singleton is dominating, but the empty set is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $V(G)$ be the set of non-empty subsets of $\mathbb N$ and join two sets by an edge whenever they intersect.  Let $D$ be the set of initial segments of $\mathbb N$.  Then subsets of $D$ are dominating if and only if they are infinite.